# How do I query a specifc child category on a page?

Tags: parent-child, wp-list-categories

I am trying to query a list of child categories that are specific to a page. In other words, if I go to the page with the slug 'us-mid-western-tour' it queries the children categories of parent cat with ID 49 and if I go to 'us-western-tour' it gets ID 21 and so on.

Here is my code so far but it is not working. Can anybody steer me in the right direction?

```
            $taxonomy     = 'tournament_category';
            $orderby      = 'name';      
            $hierarchical = 1;     
            $child        = if ( is_page('us-mid-western-tour')) {  
                          echo '49';
                         } elseif ( is_page('us-western-tour')) {
                         echo '21';
                         }
                         ;

            $args = array(
            'taxonomy'     => $taxonomy,
            'orderby'      => $orderby,
            'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
            'hide_empty'   => 0,
            'child_of'     => $child,
```

Thanks D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this

```
if ( is_page('us-mid-western-tour')) {  
    $child =  '49';
} elseif ( is_page('us-western-tour')) {
    $child = '21';
}
```

I hope it will help

Comment: Perfect thank you sonusindhu.  Wow so simple when you know how hey :)